# Dynamically fill HTML template based on the list item selected in previous view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a page: /tracks that is a list of items each with an ngclick and href item attached to them.

The href links to a view of the specific item based on the value that was passed from a function in ngclick. The href view should be populated automatically, but its not working. Relevant code:

Tracks view (Tracks controller attached):

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in vm.tracks" ng-click="vm.setTrack(item)" href="#/app/track">
{{item.name}}
</ion-item>"
```

Track view (track controller attached):

```
<ion-content>
    {{vm.currentTrack.name}}
    {{vm.currentTrack.metadata.desc}}
    {{vm.currentTrack.metadata.author}}
    {{vm.currentTrack.metadata.date}}
</ion-content>
```

Tracks controller:

```
    /** @fires $rootScope.TrackChange */
    function setTrack(track){
        vm.currentTrack = track;
       $rootScope.$emit('TrackChange', track);
    }
```

Track controller:

```
    /** @listens $rootScope.TrackChange */
    $rootScope.$on('TrackChange', function(event, data) {
        vm.currentTrack = data;
    });
```

How do I make this event work? Putting a console.log command in the listener shows that vm.currentTrack is being updated, but each time I fire a new event on click, there is an additional print out of vm.currentTrack -- the events are not being cleared. Track view prints out vm.currentTrack on the second click only for some reason. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Should I be doing something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advice you to store the `currentTrack` data in a service and inject it in both `track` and `tracks` controller or store it in a parent controller of both `track` and `tracks`, since you are switching states. The reason its not working right is that the listener you have written only gets assigned after the controller is controller is created. But the the event is fired even before the controller being created.

You fire -> switch state -> create new controller -> subscribe ... don't you think its too late? :)

*Pro Tip!* Using events in angular are signs that you are going in wrong direction.

Comment: How else do I communicate between two controllers without events?

Comment: [Providers!](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) Events bloat already eventful angularjs. Angular has ton of watchers everywhere. We don't want to overload it. For a small app it might be fine, as the app grows, it will hinder the performance. Providers are there for this precise reason. They are singletons that don't change unless the browser is refreshed.

Comment: So in another section of the app I'm writing, I have two controllers: MapController and ToolController. ToolController watches for changes in a checkbox view, then fires an event on update. Mapcontroller listens for the event and responds accordingly. Can you explain how this might be accomplished with a provider? I tried using $watch on a factory in MapController that checked for changes made, but $watch is only active when the Map View was active so that did not work.

Comment: To clarify what I'm asking is, in controllers, how can you tell if variables in factories change without using events?

Comment: 1. If they are both in the same page share the data in upper level controller. 2. If they are in different pages share the data in a service. Its not that I am totally against events, just keep it as last resort ... I'd try [inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) and providers first ..

Comment: In directives I'd try `'&'` attributes to update the upper level and through attributes to lower level components. I'd allow angular to do its job before I try to takeover.

Comment: Thanks. I've got it working now. Realized when I had tried services, I had been using them slightly incorrectly.